# indent action in tiptap 2

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tiptap

I need to perform the indent action, something like adding a margin-left in the html tag that is generated by the tip tap, I've tried everything but I can't move forward with it

`editor.chain().command().focus().indent().run()`

Answer (score 1):

Just resolved it today by referring to this https://github.com/ueberdosis/tiptap/issues/1036. Thought maybe helpful for people around here. I was using this along with twillcms. Here's what worked for me:

Create this file as indent.js

```
import { AllSelection, TextSelection } from "prosemirror-state"
import { Extension } from "@tiptap/core"

export const Indent = Extension.create({
    name: "indent",

    defaultOptions: {
        types: ["listItem", "paragraph", "heading"],
        minLevel: 0,
        maxLevel: 4 // feel free to increase
    },

    addGlobalAttributes() {
        return [
            {
                types: this.options.types,
                attributes: {
                    indent: {
                        renderHTML: attributes => {
                            return attributes.indent > this.options.minLevel ? { "data-indent": attributes.indent } : null
                        },
                        parseHTML: element => {
                            const indentLevel = Number(element.getAttribute("data-indent"))
                            return indentLevel && indentLevel > this.options.minLevel ? indentLevel : null
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    },

    addCommands() {
        const setNodeIndentMarkup = (tr, pos, delta) => {
            const node = tr?.doc?.nodeAt(pos)

            if (node) {
                const nextLevel = (node.attrs.indent || 0) + delta
                const { minLevel, maxLevel } = this.options
                const indent =
                    nextLevel < minLevel
                        ? minLevel
                        : nextLevel > maxLevel
                            ? maxLevel
                            : nextLevel

                if (indent !== node.attrs.indent) {
                    const { indent: oldIndent, ...currentAttrs } = node.attrs
                    const nodeAttrs =
                        indent > minLevel ? { ...currentAttrs, indent } : currentAttrs
                    return tr.setNodeMarkup(pos, node.type, nodeAttrs, node.marks)
                }
            }
            return tr
        }

        const updateIndentLevel = (tr, delta) => {
            const { doc, selection } = tr

            if (
                doc &&
                selection &&
                (selection instanceof TextSelection ||
                    selection instanceof AllSelection)
            ) {
                const { from, to } = selection
                doc.nodesBetween(from, to, (node, pos) => {
                    if (this.options.types.includes(node.type.name)) {
                        tr = setNodeIndentMarkup(tr, pos, delta)
                        return false
                    }

                    return true
                })
            }

            return tr
        }
        const applyIndent = direction => () => ({ tr, state, dispatch }) => {
            const { selection } = state
            tr = tr.setSelection(selection)
            tr = updateIndentLevel(tr, direction)

            if (tr.docChanged) {
                dispatch?.(tr)
                return true
            }

            return false
        }

        return {
            indent: applyIndent(1),
            outdent: applyIndent(-1)
        }
    },

    addKeyboardShortcuts() {
        return {
            Tab: () => {
                return this.editor.commands.indent()
            },
            "Shift-Tab": () => {
                return this.editor.commands.outdent()
            }
        }
    }
})
```

[image: expected functionality]

Answer (score 0):

may be you should try to make an Extension that extends Node that you wanna apply it to, add an new option there that will be parsed and converted to style property

```
import Paragraph from '@tiptap/extension-paragraph';

const CustomParagraph = Paragraph.extend({
  addAttributes() {
    return {
      indent: {
        default: '0',
        parseHTML: (element) => {
          console.log(element.getAttribute('indent'));
        },
        renderHTML: (attributes) => {
          return {
            style: `margin-left: ${attributes.indent}px`,
          };
        },
      },
    };
  },
});

export { CustomParagraph };
```

Comment: The best way to handle this is to create a Mark so that you don't have to replicate the logic in multiple Nodes.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any official extension as of now that adds indentation support in Tiptap, you'll need to create a custom extension for that. The best way to handle this is to create a [Mark](https://tiptap.dev/api/marks) so that you don't have to replicate the logic in multiple Nodes which was suggested in one of the answers.

You can have a look at this [issue](https://github.com/ueberdosis/tiptap/issues/1036#issue-864043820) to get started on the custom extension. This is mentioned as a community extension by Tiptap maintainers [here](https://github.com/ueberdosis/tiptap/issues/819). You'll probably need to tweak the code that is given in the git discussion above.

Also, somewhat unrelated, you can drop the redundant `command()` call from the command chain you have in the question.

```js
// editor.chain().command().focus().indent().run();
editor.chain().focus().indent().run();
```

Answer (score -2):

you can use `@tiptap/extension-text-indent` lib,
it already brings the action of indenting

Comment: this lib has been discontinued