# How do I indent in code-block-lowlight, a tiptab extension?extension?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, tiptap

I'm making code block using tiptab, extension-code-block-lowlight, highlight.js, and lowlight.
However, I noticed that extension-code-block-lowlight does not have an indentation feature

So I found the next solution through search. https://stackoverflow.com/a/77180487/21331174

I tested indentation with paragraph and it works fine! However, you can't just add codeBlock and test it out like this.

```
defaultOptions: {
    types: ["listItem", "paragraph", "heading", "codeBlock"],
    minLevel: 0,
    maxLevel: 8,
}
```

[image]

Because the pre tag contains data-indent.

Do you have any references or solutions? Customization is also difficult because it is not included in one element, such as paragraph tags.

I'm sorry for my inexperienced English skills, and I look forward to hearing from you!